# How to display the last inserted ID (primary key) of a table in a html textbox that is in a relationship with a foreign key of another table in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net and MVC, and I have a problem.
I know that this is something simple but I do not know how to do it. I seek advice and would like to thank you in advance for any help.

This is my problem:
I have 2 tables: table X: ID (primary key), Number; and table Y: ID (primary key), NID (foreign key with relationship with table X), etc.

What I want to know is how to display last inserted ID into the view of table Y on an Html editor for NID the last value of ID (table X)?
For example, I create a new row in table X, and when I want to create the row in table Y that corresponds with table X to automatically get the last ID inserted in the textbox or editor?

Can anybody give me some kind of reference or an example! Thank you for your help! Sorry for any bad spelling.

Comment: can you please show what have you tried . sample code

Comment: This is a small part of it var lastID = (from x in db.tbl_NIR select x.ID).Max();

Comment: And this is something from the post method of it://oi.tbl_NIR.ID = db.tbl_NIR.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault().ID;                  db.tbl_I_O.Add(oi);   db.SaveChanges(); //oi.NirID = ni.ID; //int lastID = oi.tbl_NIR.ID; //ViewBag.lastID = lastID; TempData["Msg"] = "Created Successfully!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                //var lastID = (from x in db.tbl_NIR select x.ID).Max();
                //ViewBag.NID = new SelectList(db.tbl_NIR, "ID", "NirID", oi.tbl_NIR.ID);
                return View(oi);

Comment: If it's possible can you show me an example in a add post method and in a view using a editor or something to better understand it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: so you want a sample MVC code where you post the data ? I have something realted to posting excel files and textbox values back to controller if you want I can share that

Comment: Yes, I want something to relate to. Thank you! I want to understand how to get the primary key of table X to be displayed on create new on foreign key in table Y. So if you have an example of that of a view and controller that does that please share it with me!

Comment: I added it in answer I hope it will help ypu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go . I tested this and it returned me the model properties along with files posted . This example gives you ideea how POSt method used in MVC and how to send model propertied back to controller .

```
      //-- this is the controller
     public class FileUploadDemoController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /FileUploadDemo/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // here find the last if of the FileUploadtable 
            var ctx = new TestDbContext();
            var maxId = ctx.Fileuploads.ToList().OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            var newId = maxId == null ? 1 : maxId.Id + 1;
            return View("Index", new FileUploadModel { Id= newId });
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostForm(FileUploadModel model)
        {
            // here you have NewId in model.Id method ; Now ypour table b in my case is fileeuploadhistory I want to insert a new record with this model.Id 

            using (var ctx = new TestDbContext())
            {
                var curretFile = ctx.Fileuploads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
                if (curretFile==null)
                {
                    curretFile=new FileUploadModel {   Name=model.Name , ValidFromDate= model.ValidFromDate};                        

                }
                curretFile.History = new FileUploadHistory { InsertedDate = DateTime.Now };
                ctx.Fileuploads.Add(curretFile);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }
            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
```

-- These are MY EntityFramework entities and I am using same on Views as well

```
  public class FileUploadModel
    {

        public FileUploadModel()
        {

        }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ValidFromDate { get; set; }

        public int HistoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKeyAttribute("HistoryId")]
        public virtual FileUploadHistory History { get; set; }
    }

    public class FileUploadHistory
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

-- Finaly the cshml file . The import point is to use new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } inside BeginForm .    // the page from where you will post the data . Please change you model class in place of FileUploadModel I created  for me .

```
   @model WebApplication1.Models.FileUploadModel



        @using (Html.BeginForm("PostForm", "FileUploadDemo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {

   <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-2 form-label">
                <label>ID:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Id , new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-2 form-label">
                <label>Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-2 form-label">
                <label>Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ValidFromDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-2 form-label">
                    <label>Select File<i class="required-field">*</i>:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="file" class="file-upload" style="margin: 0px;" hidden="hidden" accept=".xlsx" name="file" id="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-right text-right">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="process-submission" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but what I really want to know is how to get the last value of primary key of table X to be displayed when I try to create new row in table Y as foreign key.

Comment: Like this - table X: ID = 2, Number = 100; And What I want is to get the value 2 from table X ID into the textbox of NID of table Y on create new view?

Comment: But thank you anyway, I learned something new from your post.

Comment: give me some time I will answer after 20 mins

Comment: @JonA I updated my answer . Here now when you first load the view you will get max id of FileUploadModel table . See my controller Index method. Now after that When I post the Data this new Id comes to controller and then I have another table Called FileUploadHistory and I am inserting this new Id as FK in new table . I used EF for this and it happen automatically. I hope now your question is answered completely . I hope you accpet and like it

Comment: @JonA : To make sure I use EF code first migrations Soyou need to add them in your project . But if you dont want . the concept is same and it helps you to understand how pass Id from one table to another one .

Comment: Thanks again very much, this answer is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped . Happy coding